# JavaScript Map: How to find a key, get its value, and display it in HTML?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Beginner here.

I want to write a simple program to substitute numbers for letters as I type in an HTML textbox. (This is a developmental program to prepare for transliterating between alphabets using Unicode.)

My plan is to map numbers to letters in a JavaScript map, then use keyboard events to trigger a function to retrieve the numbers. Been floundering for a week (full-time) looking for syntax that will do it.

Most recent try:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="typespace" autofocus type="text" onkeyup="subst()"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Create map
const map = new Map {[
  [a, '1'],
  [b, '2'],
  [c, '3']
]};

// Change letter to number
function subst() {
  var input = event.key;          // Say user presses "a" key, "a" gets stored as input
  var output = map.get(input);    // Value mapped to "a" is "1"
  document.getElementById("typespace").innerHTML = output;  // Why "a" in typespace, not "1"?
}

/* Event handler needed?
typespace.addEventListener("keyup", subst(e));
*/
```

Every time I hit keys "a", "b", "c" while running http-server, all I get on screen is letters, not numbers.

I've tried (among other things): Setting up a loop in the function using "for" and an "if" statement; using map.forEach(). Also I've tried numerous ways of expressing the output statement. Nothing has worked. Clearly I'm missing something fundamental. It ought to be straightforward but it's not.

Comment: You'll need to set the `.value` of the typespace textarea, not the `.innerHTML`

Comment: Although I'd recommend to maybe use a separate a separate output area. Keep the originally typed text in the textarea, on `input` events do replace letter-by-letter in the text and output it into the `.textContent` of a separate element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a javascript object for storing the data. And capturing the event via an event handler, which you only need to use the function name and not pass parameters. Then I simply replace the key with the numerical ID from the object in the textarea's value.

```js
// Create map

const map ={
  "a": '1',
  "b": '2',
  "c": '3'
};

// Change letter to number
function subst(event){
  var input = event.key;
  var output = map[input];
  if(output){
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(input,output);
  }
}

typespace.addEventListener("keyup", subst);
```

```html
    <textarea id="typespace" autofocus type="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: This code does what I envisaged, thanks imvain! To make it work in my GitHub codespace, I did have to add one event attribute back into my <textarea>, namely onKeyUp="subst(event)".

Answer (score 0):

```
**this isn't only limited to an *abc*  this works will all a-z**
```

it's suppose to change the ascii math if you want to convert in other roles you can invent

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="Custa">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="typespace" autofocus type="text" onkeyup="subst()"></textarea>
<span id="okpal"></span>
<script>
    

function subst() {
  var input = event.key;          // Say user presses "a" key, "a" gets stored as input
 // console.log(input.charCodeAt(0)-96);
  obj=document.getElementById("okpal");
//  old=obj.innerHTML;
  obj.innerHTML+=(input.charCodeAt(0)-96)+' ';
 // console.log(old);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great idea, Constantin, for expediting key:value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems in your code. First, when you create the map, you are using {} instead of () to instantiate the object. second, it may be best to use a document `querySelector()` and `addEvetListener()` to add the `keyup` event listener. third, you'll need to set the value of a textbox with `.value`, rather than `innerHTML`, since it is a form input rather than tag where you nest inner HTML. Try this to get you going.

```js
// Create map
const mymap = new Map ([
  ['a', '1'],
  ['b', '2'],
  ['c', '3']
]);

// Change letter to number
document.querySelector( '#typespace' ).addEventListener( 'keyup', ( event ) => {
  var output = mymap.get( event.key );    // Value mapped to "a" is "1"
  event.currentTarget.value = output;  // Why "a" in typespace, not "1"?
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="typespace" autofocus type="text"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I caught my mistake with the curly braces, also my letters in the map needed quotation marks. You confirmed my suspicion that an EventListener was lacking. This code runs like dream for replacing one character at a time.